# EmberJS architecture overview

Tags: model-view-controller, architecture, ember.js

I'm looking for an explanatory video / writeup that would present the different components / patterns of an EmberJS application. I'm familiar with a couple of MVC architectures however this design pattern is very flexible. For example different frameworks seem to understand controllers differently. There also seem to be things that are specific to Ember such as a router and routes.

These slides http://www.lukemelia.com/devblog/archives/2012/08/23/architecting-ember-js-apps/ seem to be more or less what I want. Unfortunately, I was unable to find a working video to go together with them.

The materials posted on EmberJS site seem to follow a tutorial format. This is *not* at all what I want. Instead of learning how to build things instantly, I want to understand the general architecture first so that I know what kind of code should go where.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gave an "Introduction to Ember.js" talk somewhat more recently that might be more helpful: http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2013/03/29/introduction-to-ember-js/ The page has embeds for slides as well as video.

I heartily endorse your approach to learning Ember, too. Understanding how responsibilities are divided in Ember and how those layers relate is a big part of creating elegant, maintainable apps.

Answer (score 1):

The tag wiki lists some great video resources at the bottom.

You might send Luke a message to see if he has a copy of that presentation, he's still very active in the community.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ember.js/info

Comment: Sadly, I think the video was lost when Cloudee shut down last September (I didn't act fast enough to download it).